# How to set initial value in Django UsercreationForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am beginner in Django and developing a user registration page using the UserCreationForm from django.contrib.auth.forms. But, unable to set the initial values for password1 and password2 fields.

My requirement is when opening the usercreation form the password and re-enter password fields should get filled with an default password.

I have tried this way but unable to achieve this requirement.

views/user.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()

else:
    form = UserCreationForm(initial={'password1':'testing123','password2':'testing123'})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is your form?

Comment: I didn't get you. you mean forms.py ?

Comment: are you using a custom form or you are importing a form from django

Comment: What's the point of setting default values for passwords actually ???

Comment: You should certainly not do this. Why would you want to offer a default password?

Comment: I posted an answer and realized that it is not addressing the question of why you need it. Deleted after sometime. I went to the user creation form and tried out a possibility and it worked. What you are trying to achieve will work if render_value is set to True. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.PasswordInput.render_value https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py

Comment: i am importing form from django @mohammedqudah

Comment: offering default password is requirement @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: I am using django form for user registeration service @SandeepBalagopal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very bad idea to pre populate with default password. But however this is general idea about how to achive that. And also I recommend to extend the UserCreationForm and do the rest./

```
# Create form variable...
form = UserCreationForm(initial={
    'password2': 'password',
    'password1': 'password', 
    'username': 'rajasimon'})

# Assign render_value to True
form.fields['password1'].widget.render_value = True
form.fields['password2'].widget.render_value = True

# Return template with form...
return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Without extend the form is it possible ? help will be apprciated